# A Conversion problem featuring Significant figures

Tags: homework-and-exercises, unit-conversion

What is the speed of a car going v=1.000 mile per hour in SI units? You can do each conversion separately. Use the facts that 1mile=1609 meters and 1hour=3600 seconds.
Express your answer in meters per second to four significant figures.

Okay first I set the problem to the right conversions.
I do this

$(1000 miles / 1 hour)$ * $(1609 meters / 1 miles)$ * $ *(1hour/ 3600 seconds)$

Thus I get 446.9 m/s however this is not the right answer. I could use some guidence towards where I went wrong.

Comment: Is the car going 1.000 miles per hour or 1,000 miles per hour? There's an odd decimal point in the first sentence.

Comment: Perhaps this is why I got the problem wrong let me revaluate the problem.

Comment: Well, first, what is the correct answer?

Comment: The correct answer is .4469 m/s

Comment: So that might be the issue, then.

Comment: Strange:  the *real* right answer is $0.4470$, if you ignore the rounded value of $1609$ and use the correct, exact values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1.000 miles / 1 hour)$ * $(1609 meters / 1 miles)$ * $ *(1hour/ 3600 seconds)$ 
 Thus $.4469$ meter/second$